# Posted date is serialized to wrong date with 1 day off

Tags: java, java-time

[image]

I post to my endpoint with data `departureTime: "2019-10-21"`, and I output the received departureTime variable in my spring program.

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RequestMapping(value="/travel/query", method= RequestMethod.POST)
public ArrayList<TripResponse> query(@RequestBody QueryInfo info,@RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers){

    if(info.getStartingPlace() == null || info.getStartingPlace().length() == 0 ||
            info.getEndPlace() == null || info.getEndPlace().length() == 0 ||
            info.getDepartureTime() == null){
        System.out.println("[Travel Service][Travel Query] Fail.Something null.");
        ArrayList<TripResponse> errorList = new ArrayList<>();
        return errorList;
    }
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    Calendar ca = Calendar.getInstance();
    ca.setTime(info.getDepartureTime());
    System.out.println("Departure date is " + format.format(ca.getTime()));

    ...
}


public class QueryInfo {

    @Valid
    @NotNull
    private String startingPlace;

    @Valid
    @NotNull
    private String endPlace;

    @Valid
    @NotNull
    private Date departureTime;

    public QueryInfo(){
        //Default Constructor
    }

    public String getStartingPlace() {
        return startingPlace;
    }

    public void setStartingPlace(String startingPlace) {
        this.startingPlace = startingPlace;
    }

    public String getEndPlace() {
        return endPlace;
    }

    public void setEndPlace(String endPlace) {
        this.endPlace = endPlace;
    }

    public Date getDepartureTime() {
        return departureTime;
    }

    public void setDepartureTime(Date departureTime) {
        this.departureTime = departureTime;
    }
}
```

The console shows "Departure date is 2019-10-20".

The server running my spring program should be in UTC-7 timezone.

Any idea why this error happens? How do I do minimal changes to fix it?

Edit:

I run

```
 System.out.println(ca.getTimeZone().toString());
```

it outputs `sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/Los_Angeles"...`. I think it's correct.

Comment: How is `departureTime` defined? Any annotations?

Comment: This is almost certainly a timezone issue.

Comment: Does Calender.getTimeZone() match your expected timezone?

Comment: @Anish Your edits in my question title are confusing to me. "The date is shown wrong in the headers", it suggests it is the header that shows the wrong date, while in my question header is the input, there is no way it can be wrong. I will revert it.

Comment: @Andreas it doesn't have any annotations.

Comment: @Martin'sRun see you edit. It's expected.

Comment: @Gqqnbig Ok !! no problem. I just suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid the use of `SimpleDateFormat` & `Calendar`, instead use `ZonedDateTime`.

Example :

```
ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

Sample output :

```
2019-10-22
```

Or if you want to carry on with the old APIs from `java.util` package, then you have to use this :

```
ca.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")); // to set the time zone for using calendar API.
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")); // set timezone for formatter.
```

Comment: In any case a good suggestion (or maybe `LocalDate`if the time of day doesn’t matter)! I am unsure whether it will be enough to solve the questioner’s problem.

Comment: @OleV.V. Yes, I agree with you. If OP tells what happens after using this. Then, there is a possibility that his problem can be solved. :)

Comment: My input does not specify timezone. When my application receives the date string, can it interpret as local time without timezone? I cannot change the type of DepartureTime from Date to LocalDate because it will affect all parts of the system.

Comment: @Gqqnbig  Probably you can set the timezone - `ca.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))`.

Comment: got you. It seems it's only a display error, that I have to set `format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))`. The value itself in Date is correct.

Answer (score 0):

`Calendar.getInstance()` will set the timezone depending on where the server is hosted. Therefore, if you are not in UTC-7 timezone, you will see a discrepancy in time.

The best way around this is generally to work with a specific timezone, such as UTC, or any other timezone being used for your data. Then you can obtain a `Calendar` for that specific timezone as follows:

```
Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution(not the smart one though, but works) can be, you define your `dateField` in your `DTOs` as String field. So, what you send you will get the same, no date conversion based on timezone or other stuff. Then you can convert that string to your favourable date `format/timezone`.